# Current is same everywhere in the circuit

Tags: electric-current, charge

Why don't charges pile up at the vicinity  of resistor as charge flowing out of resistor is slow at one side of resistor but on the other side charge starts to pile up to enter resistor?

Comment: charges do pile up, see this: http://ithaki.eng.auth.gr/elab/microscopic-view-of-elecrrical-circuits.pdf and this Muller: "A semiquantitative treatment of surface charges in DC circuits", Am. J. Phys. 80 (9), September 2012

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* user264745! Why do you say that the flow of charge out a resistor is slow at one side? If charge were to continue to build up on the incoming side, wouldn't that accumulating charge *repel* the 'slow' charges to move faster away from the resistor?

Comment: That accumulating charge will create a electric field which will oppose the incoming electron and this electric field push the out going electron. Well, it is the same explanation given in Griffith book. I think it is also a great intuitive explanation.

Comment: @hyportnex That article is old (and unpublished), and I believe that Sherwood's understanding has evolved over time. [Here is a more recent, published, peer-reviewed version](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.5095939).  His arguments are compelling, but he considers a thin wire rather than a resistor, and I think the situation is different.  You can't make the area vs. current argument for a resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the current flowing out is *not* faster than the current flowing in.

If charges moved faster when exiting the resistor, then they will soon deplete. They will all soon have left that end of the resistor. Then we'll have to wait until a new charge has flown through before we see another one moving fast away from the resistor. In other words, we will have a queuing up of charges *flowing in* but no of charges *flowing out*.

- Those charges flowing in are moving slower, but they are also many, many more.
- Those charges flowing out are moving faster, but they are also much fewer.

These two effects will have to balance out. The current is the total charge moving past a point per second and with faster but fewer charges we can still reach the same current as with more but slower charges.

We know that the current must be the same at all points along a non-split wire because of Kirchhoff's current law. It simply says that if there is no building up of charges, no accumulation, anywhere then in-going current per second must equal all out-going current per second. (If more flows in than out, then we have a built-up - if more flows out than in, then soon there will be no more to flow out and it.)

Comment: Amazing!! satisfactory answer. so the final conclusion is, if I connected a battery to a resistor positive terminal on the right side and negative terminal on the left side. Dirft velocity of electron at left side of resistor is slow and on the other side dirft velocity of electron is high.

Comment: static surface charges do accumulate along the wire, see this http://ithaki.eng.auth.gr/elab/microscopic-view-of-elecrrical-circuits.pdf

Comment: @hypertnex True, and there are also certain circuits and components that accumulate charge. In this answer I'm assuming steady current, which we have when all such accumulation has stabilised.

Comment: @user264745 The current being constant on either side of the resistor can mean two things: Either more charge flow in than out, with those flowing out being faster (this is the scenario I have described), or equally many flow in as out but they have all stabilised at the same same drift speed. You will see these two scenarios at different points in a circuit. But in the simple case of a battery connected directly across a resistor, I believe we are dealing with the first case as you describe here, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much @steeven

Comment: The OP likes your answer, and if he or she is satisfied, the OP should mark this as accepted.  However, your answer does not answer the question "Does charge build up at the ends of a resistor, or doesn't it?".   Charge can build up in a "clump" during the transient phase.   Once steady state is reached, the current remains constant but the drift velocity changes as resistivity and cross section changes.  All I'm saying is that your answer does not preclude the existence of charge accumulation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when electric charge flows in a closed circuit, the current remain same everywhere in it.

The electric charge leaving one end of a conductor is equal to the charge entering the other end of the conductor. Thus no charge stores or piles up in a conductor when an electric current flows through it. This also satisfies the Law of Conservation of Charge for a circuit assuming it as an isolated system.

Comment: Here is my hypothesis - drift velocity of electron is higher in resistor because there is high intensity electric field. So that current is same everywhere in the circuit. (just correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Well, electric current is the amount of charge moving per unit time across a section of conductor. So a large amount of charge moving with low drift velocity can given same current as given by small amount charge moving with high drift velocity. We can conclude that electric current is dependent on both the amount of charge & its drift velocity. Electric Current is governed by both amount of charge & its drift velocity in a conductor.

Comment: @peter, but both the material have different resistivity. So the medium of transportation of charge and electric field strength change in both the material. There might be some other factor playing role in flowing of current which I don't no.

Comment: you are wrong http://ithaki.eng.auth.gr/elab/microscopic-view-of-elecrrical-circuits.pdf

Comment: @hyportnex OK, may be I am wrong. Can you please point out where I am wrong if you don't mind?

Comment: you wrote " no charge stores or piles up in a conductor when an electric current flows", this is not true, see this: ithaki.eng.auth.gr/elab/… and this Muller: "A semiquantitative treatment of surface charges in DC circuits", Am. J. Phys. 80 (9), September 2012

Comment: OK, if charge stores in a conductor then it must be charged like a capacitor i.e. when we stop current through a conductor, it becomes charged. Does it follow fundamental law of charge conservation assuming a conductor as an isolated system ?

Answer (score 0):

**They actually do pile up**

*But it is not because charges move slowly at one end and faster at the other. current remains same throughout*

even before electrons start moving and making a current, something called electric Force (its actually electric field but not sure you know that) propogates from one end of battery to the other end at a very high speed. It is only after this Force reaching a point, the charges at that point start to move. If the speed at which this force travelled was small, we would see current slowly building up from the ends and finally, all charges moving with same speed. (ie:same current) So, for a smal time, current is not. constant throughout. *But in reality the speed with which this force travels is the speed of light and hence, the small time for which current is different is negligibly small. So current is constant throughout*

*why charges accumulate?*
It is becuse there exist a voltage across a Resistor. A voltage across the resistor can only be generated by charge differences across its ends.

Comment: “Resistor. A voltage across the resistor can only be generated by charge differences across its ends.” That’s not correct. There’s no difference in the amount of charge between the ends of the resistor. There is a drop in electrical potential and electrical potential energy that is converted to heat. The voltage  between the ends of the resistor is the work done by the electric field per unit charge to move the charge through the resistor

Comment: There is. Though the rate of flow of charge is same, the charge is different across its ends. charge is the fundemental cause of all electric fields and potentials. Without a charge difference, there is no reason for a potential difference.

Comment: Your statement that potential difference is just due to the work done to move against $\vec E$ is true but the cause of $\vec E$ is a charge difference

Comment: The cause of the electric field is the voltage source in the circuit, for example a battery

Comment: A resistor is a passive device. It is not a voltage generator, I.e. it is not a source of an Emf like a battery

Comment: Yes it does not generate voltage... who said that? The ultimate source of potential is the battery. But across the Resistor, it is the charge separation that creates the Electric field. or equivalently, as you would say - the potential difference would cause a charge difference (this may be the way you like).  the existence of a potential difference implies and implies a charge separation.

Comment: The resistor does not separate charge. The voltage difference is due to the charge losing electrical potential energy when it passes through the resistor. With that said I am leaving this discussion

Comment: @BobD surface charges actually *do* pile up in the very beginning of the current flow, and that is static electricity in addition to the magnetic field of the current. Without that static field there is no current. An electron in the middle of the circuit does not "feel" the field of the battery, it only feels the field of the local surface charge. You may say that the battery builds up the surface charge electron by electron and that surface charge is the one actually that moves the current!

Comment: @Bob_d an excellent discussion of this subject is here http://ithaki.eng.auth.gr/elab/microscopic-view-of-elecrrical-circuits.pdf

Comment: @BobD, I have to disagree with you - there *is* a difference in charge (density) at the ends of a resistor (and through it) as well as on the two wires connecting the resistor to the source of emf. [Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVOWk.png) I quickly found at Research Gate from a [New Approach to Introduce Basic Concepts in Electricity](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/300765070_New_Approach_to_Introduce_Basic_Concepts_in_Electricity).