# Confusion regarding drift velocity and potential

Tags: electricity, electric-current, voltage

From [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552895/current-is-same-everywhere-in-the-circuit/552907#552907) I understood that the drift velocity of electrons decreases further into the circuit. But my book says that electrons move with constant velocity throughout the circuit, and both of them make sense to me but I'm confused which one is actually correct. If I believe that drift velocity decreases but electron density increases, it helps me understand how current remains constant throughout the circuit, but that means electrons are decelerating. Now if thats the case, it means electrons are constantly losing energy, but they also gain energy because of the potential difference, so their velocity remains constant(as per my book) which also makes sense. But that contradicts the above post, so at this point I'm totally confused what to believe. I'm in 10th grade a layman in electricity, so I'm sorry if this question sounds dumb. But this doubt has been killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *current* (that is the rate of flow 0f charge) is the same at all points in a circuit consisting of conductors (or just lengths of wire) connected in series across a battery.

If the moving charges are free electrons (charge -$e$), the current at any place in the circuit where the cross-sectional area of the conductor is $A$ is
$$I=(–)\nu A v e$$
in which $\nu$ is the number of free electrons per unit volume of conductor and $v$ is their drift velocity.

If, for example, the conductors are all made of the same material, $\nu$ will be the same throughout, so we can deduce that $A\nu$ will be the same everywhere. So if the conductor is thinner in one part of the circuit, $v$ will be larger!

Drift velocities are typically less than 1 mm/s, so you don't need to worry about kinetic energy changes when the electrons speed up or slow down. The only important energy change in a resistive circuit is from electrical potential energy to extra thermal vibration energy of the atoms (or ions), due to collisions between the free electrons and the ions.

Comment: So the electrons slowing down is a negligible energy change?

Comment: This doesn't fully answer my question- you said drift velocity change is negligible so it doesn't matter,  but the change in velocity is enough to affect the current? Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: (a)  I've tried to answer the question in your first two sentences about drift velocity. You now ask whether "the change in velocity is enough to affect the current?" Please study the equation I gave.  In my opinion this needs getting straight before you consider energy changes. (b) "drift velocity change is negligible so it doesn't matter," I said that changes in kinetic energy are too small to matter. But the drift velocity affects the collision rate, and that *does* matter in terms of energy! But get the relationship between $v$ and $I$ sorted first. Then ask a question about potential?

Comment: But the only energy gained by the electrons is from. the potential difference, that's why electrical energy is $=Vit$. To make sure that holds true, the electrons need to have a constant velocity so that there is no change in kinetic energy, and only an increase in electric potential energy. So if I consider that $\Delta KE$ is $0$, then is change in velocity also too small to matter? If that's the case then the current doesn't end up as constant according to the hyperlinked post which i sent

Comment: "the electrons need to have a constant velocity so that there is no change in kinetic energy" The change in KE is negligible from an energy accounting point of view. But the drift velocity is related to the current by the equation that I gave, and the drift velocity will change if there is a change in conductor (for example  a change in its cross-sectional area) as we go round the circuit.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thanks!